# Space-efficient data structure for analytical querying of multiple branching evolutions of a dataset

Tags: data-structures, database-theory, data-compression

#### Problem Description

I have a *data state space*: a set of data sets, each of which can be modelled as a collection of arbitrary key-value pairs. These data sets are each a branch of evolution of a parent data set, forming a tree (not a lattice; data sets branch but do not merge.) The root of the tree is an empty data set.

I'm not looking at/exploring the entirety of this data state space. Rather, I have a listing of all the leaf-node data sets which exist in use in the real world. I only care about these leaf-node data sets, and (sometimes) their ancestors.

I wish to find (or create!) a persistent (on-disk, distributed/sharded if necessary) data-structure for storing and querying of these in-use data sets. I would also accept a database management system that happens to have such a data-structure (or assemblage of features to simulate such a data structure) as a feature. I just have a practical need to store and query this data!

#### Requirements

This data structure would need the following operations:

- **define** a new data set in the store, in terms of a **parent data-set identifier/handle**; and a **set of key-value "writes"** which would create this data set if applied to the referenced parent;
- **open** the store with respect to a particular data-set identifier, returning a data-set handle;
- **query** the store + data-set handle for a **particular key's value**;
- **query** the store + data-set handle for the key-value pairs in a given **key range**;
- **query** the store + data-set handle for a **dump** of all key-value pairs in the data set.
- (optionally) obtain a **cursor** against a store + data-set handle + initial key, and use it to **iterate** forward/backward through key-value pairs, with each iteration returning a key-value pair.

Constraints imposed by the data:

- Many leaf-node data sets in the state space will contain **billions** of key-value pairs.
- Many leaf-node data sets are more than **10 million levels** "deep" or "high" away from the root.
- Many data sets are trivial changes from their parent, consisting of **one** update or even **zero** updates (but will retain a distinct identity in the zero-update case.)
- Many data sets are non-trivial, consisting of **hundreds of thousands** of updates to their parent.
- Each branch node in the tree has, on average, **1.5 children** (most have only one; some have two; very few have more than two.) The tree mostly consists of long linear segments of nodes, with branch nodes forking between a new "main branch" on one side; and a short, terminal "side branch" on the other.

Operational constraints:

- The **read** operations must be **time-efficient** (i.e. soft real-time/bounded latency), as the point of this data store is to serve read-heavy analytical queries.
- **Insertion** of new data sets into the store must **scale** into the millions without going exponential; but otherwise inserts can be fairly slow, taking on the order of seconds to commit a new data-set definition into the store.
- **Opening** a data set within the store can be time-costly (again ~seconds), though again, this overhead must grow slowly-enough to allow one to open a data-set buried "deeply" in the store. This "free" time can be used to unpack the data set from any compression/delta-encoding format, to cache data or required intermediate data-structures from disk into memory, etc.
- The store must be as **space-efficient on disk** as possible (allowing whatever disk-space overhead is required to satisfy the other constraints.) I don't have petabytes laying around to spread this store onto!

#### Discussion

The disk-space usage consideration is where things get interesting, IMHO.

Without a requirement of disk-space efficiency, the naive solution is to just have full copies of every distinct data-set stored separately in their own read-indexed storage files, possibly then distributing distinct data-sets onto their own network shards so read queries can be separately routed to them.

But this naive solution would throw the storage requirements for this state-space (recall, ~billions of KV pairs each, ~millions of nodes) into multi-petabyte territory, and I don't have that kind of space.

Intuitively, from experience tuning analytical database systems, I would expect a *good* on-disk data structure for OLAP backing-storage (including all required indices) to introduce no more than a 10x overhead on top of a change-data-capture representation of the source data. The change-data-capture representation of all these data sets (i.e. the representations that would be fed to the **define** operation above) currently sums to ~50GB; so I'd intuitively expect this data structure would demand no more than ~500GB of disk. Am I crazy to expect that?

I know I can get some easy wins in terms of storage overhead for general "deduplication" of data sets, by just relying on a filesystem with block-level copy-on-write, where each data-set in the state space becomes its own copy-on-write snapshot, and the snapshots form a tree. But this seems like it *wouldn't* scale operationally, because either I'd be using a sorted flat-file data set format (in which case inserts "in the middle" of data cause storage-overhead explosion in descendant snapshots) or I'd be using something like an on-disk LSM tree [e.g. LevelDB] or B+-tree [e.g. LMDB] (in which case each snapshot would add another "level" to the tree, causing either an explosion of file inodes in the case of LevelDB, or a fragmentation of each file into tiny per-layer extents in the LMDB case), in the end meaning that reads to a million-branch-deep data set in such a store would have quite a lot of overhead at the filesystem bookkeeping level.

I would guess that a *good* data-structure for this would involve, at some level:

- tries (HAMTs?)
- a notion of "keyframes" vs "interstitial frames", for representing the trivial change sets
- a notion of "highly-connected routes" through the tree, where "major branches" are repacked (defragmented?) and "minor branches" are re-stored in terms of their difference from a "major branch"

I'm aware of **Datomic**, which seems to have an architecture and set of operations similar to what I'm looking for; but which supports only a linear timeline, rather than a tree of timeline-branches. I'm unclear on whether its architectural design could be extended to support branching time without fundamental changes.

I'm also aware of what **blockchain** systems (e.g. Ethereum) are doing with *merkle patricia trie*-based storage. I've evaluated doing exactly this, but—at least as blockchains themselves implement this approach—the read performance *doesn't* scale for analytical workloads. (It works for these systems, because their evolution-steps are OLTP workloads, computing almost always against a "main branch" state—the outcome of the previous most-recent computation—which is therefore cached almost-entirely into memory. Everything other than the most-recent "main branch" state is able to be considered "cold." None of this is true for an OLAP use-case; OLAP queries look at arbitrary branches of a state-space at arbitrary times, with no branch or node being "hot.") I would expect that some modification (relaxation?) of this approach might be suitable, though, since the *merkle* aspect of the *merkle patricia tries* used here is only relevant for trustless multi-party state sharing, which doesn't come up in this design.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a [persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) map data structure.  A reasonable choice would be a [persistent binary balanced tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Trees) or a [persistent hash array mapped trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Persistent_hash_array_mapped_trie); with these choices, every operation can be done in $O(\log n)$ time or $O(1)$ time.  You can store these data structures on disk and the disk overhead should be not too large: $O(n+\log m)$ or $O(n+m)$, where $n$ is the total number of items stored and $m$ is the number of "define" operations used to construct all of the datasets.

Since you have a read-mostly workload, as an optimization you can use your "opening" to load all of the key values in the data structure into memory and construct an in-memory hashmap that serves as a faster index into the data structure, and throw away this hashmap whenever memory gets tight or when you are done with that data structure; or you can build up such an index on the fly as a cache of where certain keys are located.  Or, the data structure might perform adequately for your needs even without this.